# How to remove a part of edge loop which deforms my object?

Tags: edges

I have just started off with blender, so please forgive me if I misuse the terminologies.

I have created an object by merging together a cylinder and a cube as shown in the screenshots below.
I created edge loops to sharpen the corners, which worked fine. It caused some deformities at the top face of the cylinder which I fixed by creating an inset.

[image: edge loop to sharpen corners]

But on the sides of the cylinder, it creates a pinched effect.
[image]
I tried for really long to remove the extra edge, but could not do so without introducing more complexities and deformations.

Is there a way to deal with this?
It seems that this must be a very common scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of topology behaves well under subdivision, despite the large number of edges meeting where the circular and straight boundaries meet. I would start with a lower number of edges on the cylinder, myself, it's easier to work with. Let a subdivision modifier do the work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can see what you have done there with the edges, but I am hardly able to follow it through. I just recreated and ruined the entire object thrice now. Is there any tutorial out there which can explain the general thought process to reorient vertices. I had been running away from getting into this, but looks like I can't ignore this for long.


edit:
For example, I can see that the faces need to always have 4 vertices, but how do I arrive at those? I delete one of the vertex and always end up with 5 remaining.

Comment: This [blog](http://topologyguides.com/) is often recommended here on SE, and I found going through these [exercises](https://www.youtube.com/user/neogen23/videos) to be a pretty good start. There is actually quite a limited range of patterns to become familiar with.

Comment: Thank you so much for those links! These look like blender jackpots. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Select the edge loop by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+RMB</kbd>
Then press<kbd>X</kbd> or Delete button, right on the bottom you will find an **Edge Loop** option. That should do the trick.

Edit : Make sure you are on edge select mode.

Comment: Thanks. This does not help though. It deletes the edge loop but disturbs the shape in other ways.